# Referenced assembly is not the same version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

This is a asp.net MVC 3 application using nhibernate.

In my proje1.Data assembly I have all my nhibernate related code, and that also includes a HTTPmodule that handles the session.

I had to reference System.Web because it needs access to HttpContext, and after I added System.Web I am getting the below error.

I'm confused as this is a new project and everything seems to be .NET 4.0

```
Warning 5   The referenced assembly "E:\dev\proj1\src\proj1.Data\bin\Debug\proj1.Data.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.    ConsoleTest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your proj1.Data project targeted for ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" instead of just ".NET Framework 4"?  You can check this by checking the properties for that project.  It will be listed under "Target framework:" in the Application tab.

Comment: All of them are targetting .net framework 4, none have client profile selected.  does that make sense?

Comment: That's very strange. What is ConsoleTest? It appears at the end of the error message you posted.  I'm guessing that's just some sort of test harness with a reference to proj1.Data?  And that is targeted to .NET Framework 4 as well?